# オリジナルのクラスをjsonのDataに変換する方法を教えてください。

Tags: swift, json

swiftで独自のクラスをvalueに含むDictionaryをJSONのDataに変換する方法を教えてください。

コードは以下のようです。

```
class Test {
    let value: String
    init(_ val: String) {
        value = val
    }
}

let test = Test("test")

let dictionary: Dictionary<String, Test> = ["The": test]

do{
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
}catch{
}
```

実行環境はplaygroundです。
エラーは下から3行目のtry文で起きます。
エラーメッセージを見る限りだと、独自のクラスをJSONに変換できないということみたいなのですが、何のクラスに変換すればJSONからDictionaryに変換し直す時に、元のDictionaryと同じものが入手できるのでしょうか。
また、以下の方法でそのクラスから元のクラスに戻せるのでしょうか。

```
let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as? Dictionary<String, Test>
```

回答していただきたい点は、
・独自のクラスをJSONDataに変換する方法
・変換したクラスから独自のクラスに戻す方法
の2点です。
わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、この2点についての回答をお願いいたします。

Comment: `JSONSerialization`クラスは、JSON形式のデータ(object, array, string, number, true/false, null)をそれぞれ、Objective-Cのオブジェクト(`NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSNumber`, `NSNull`)に変換するもので、それ以外の独自データ型が含まれている場合には、JSONに変換することはできませんし、JSONから独自データ型が含まれるデータ構造を直接取り出すこともできません。Swift 4にはそのようなことが簡単にできるような仕組みが採用されたのですが、Swift 4は御使用可能でしょうか？どうしても現在のSwift(Swift 3)でと言うことになると、上記したObjective-Cのデータ型と独自データ型との変換の部分は自前でコードを書いてやることになります。

Comment: やはり無理なのですね。全て自前でコードを書こうと思います。iOSアプリでリリースすることを目標にしているので、まだswift4は使うことができません。教えていただきありがとうございました。